# mysql / php selecting rows and sending emails not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a PHP / mySQL script where users can list products and other users can be alerted when a product with a certain keyword is listed. For some strange reason, the users are never getting the emails and the email action doesn't seem to be executed either, no matter how I write it.

Before I explain more, here is the code. This part here runs the approval of each of the products (as there may be more than 1 approved at once). This part is working correctly:

```
            $approve_array = $db->implode_array($_REQUEST['approve']);
            foreach ($_REQUEST['approve'] as $value)
            {
                $cnt_details = $db->get_sql_row("SELECT product_id, active, approved, closed, deleted, list_in, category_id, addl_category_id FROM 
                    db_products WHERE product_id='" . intval($value) . "'");

                $mail_input_id = $cnt_details['auction_id'];
                include('notification_approved.php');               

            }
```

Note that it uses notification_approved.php which is the piece of code that sends the emails. The contents of notification_approved.php are as follows:

```
<?

if ( !defined('INCLUDED') ) { die("Access Denied"); }

$keyword_search_string = 'teddybear';

$sql_select_products = $db->get_sql_row("SELECT kw.keyword, a.product_id, a.name AS item_name,  
    u.name AS user_name, u.username, u.email FROM db_keywords_watch kw
    INNER JOIN db_products a ON a.product_id='" . $mail_input_id . "'
    INNER JOIN db_users u ON u.user_id=kw.user_id WHERE 
    MATCH (kw.keyword) AGAINST ('" . $keyword_search_string . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");

ob_start();
var_dump($row_details);
$data = ob_get_clean();
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);    

while ($row_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_products))
{
    $text_message = 'this is the text message';
    $html_message = 'this is the html message';         
    send_mail('receiver@email.com', 'Keyword Alert', $text_message, 'sender@email.com', $html_message, null, true);
}
?>
```

I have further simplified the above to one only email address, instead of pulling it from the database, to track down the problem, but not even with a static email it's working.

Everything until there is working fine. I also tracked down the "$sql_select_auctions" which is correctly returning the arrays. I did an output to file right BEFORE "while ($row_details ..." and it output the array correctly, so in my opinion the problem is somwhere after that "while ($row_details ..." part.

The array is output correctly as:

```
cat file.txt
Array
(
    [0] => teddybear
    [keyword] => teddybear
    [1] => 172
    [auction_id] => 172
    [2] => a cute teddybear
    [item_name] => a cute teddybear
    [3] => First Last
    [user_name] => First Last
    [4] => theusername
    [username] => theusername
    [5] => receiver@email.com
    [email] => receiver@email.com
)
```

I am also including the function "fetch_array" for reference, however that is not the problem I think as it's used on a dozen other places without problems:

```
    function fetch_array ($query_result)
    {
            $result = @mysql_fetch_array($query_result);

            if ($this->sql_error($result))
            {
                    die ($this->display_error(MSG_ERROR_MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY, $this->sql_error($result)));
            }

            return $result;
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong? I'm at a loss and have been at this for hours :(

Comment: Are you sure that send_mail() function is actually working? Have you tried doing something like `var_dump($row_details)` inside the while() loop to see what's coming out?

Comment: Just tried that, writing var_dump to file actually ..and it's not writing anything. That's the strange part..it's almost like nothing inside while works, while right before it, it works fine.

Comment: Updated my original post with the "var_dump".

Comment: So the db call is working fine, so start debugging the mail system. Make sure it's working, make sure the email's actually going out, make sure the email's not being dumped as spam. blah blah blah. These are all things YOU have to check

Comment: Yep, did that. I use the same email function without problems in similar notifications. The only difference is that the other notifications don't use the "while" loop. It seems like anything inside "while" is not working. I even tried writing just "hello world" inside the "while" loop and not even that is working.

Comment: just because it works fine elsewhere means nothing here. you're doing email. that means even if EVERYTHING works perfectly on your server, the receiving end is still free to decide THIS particular email is spam and trash it. email means there's at least FOUR players in the game. your code, your mail server, the receiving mail server, and the receiving mail client.

Answer (score 0):

Is send_mail() your own function or are you using a php function? I would try just using mail() for the time being as it seems to be the only base email function for php. Test:

```
mail('receiver@email.com', 'Keyword Alert', $text_message);
```

If that works, you can build your additional headers and add it to the mail() function ala http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Yes, it's a function, but it's working correctly. I have other notifications which are however without a while loop and those are working correctly with send_mail. I'm pulling out my hairs over this. It seems to get the arrays correctly right before the while. It's only after the while where the problems appear to be.

Comment: In your while loop, what do you get if you comment out your mail function and add print_r($row_details);?

Comment: Nothing at all, actually.